# Scraping Google Search Results in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get the links from the search results. Can someone please help with with the regular expression to do this? I've got this, and it doesn't work:

```
 preg_match_all("/<h3(.*)><a href=\"(.*)\"(.*)<\/h3>/", $result, $matches);
```

Comment: Trying to get the URL for each of the search results (not adwords).

Comment: You can't really use regular expressions for HTML parsing. Use the [DOM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or another DOM parser.

Comment: Why do you have to scrape search results when there's a Google API that makes it a whole lot easier?! http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/web.html

Answer (score 5):

Your patterns are likely having the biggest issues because of the greedy vs lazy nature of it. Changing it to the following should solve that issue...

```
preg_match_all('#<h3.*?><a href="(.*?)".*?</h3>#', $result, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

There are possibly a few rare URLs that could mess the pattern up, but chances are you won't run into one. I will point out that stillstanding has a good point though using the API would be a better option.

As for people that blanket answer with "You can't parse HTML with Regex, use a DOM"... Whilst you cannot create a generic HTML parser (and should be using DOM for that task), you can match patterns in a set of text you know follows a certain structure, the fact that structure is HTML is irrelevant. Yes, if Google change their layout it will probably break, but this is also probably true of a DOM Parser. (P.S. I'm well aware this will probably get down-voted by the sheeple).

Comment: +1 for fighting back against the regex haters! Sometimes it is appropriate to use regex on HTML, if you're not trying to parse the DOM completely.

Comment: I love you. This is the regexp i was looking for. It would be cool if there would be a code, that could get the next link.
Thank you :)